# Linux Ubuntu Samba не могу подключиться в сетевой папке

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Есть локальная сеть. К этой сети не могу подключить принтер. Samba подключен, все настроено, но при попытке зайти в папку просит пароль и логин.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Значит не всё настроено. Где логи и конфиги?

Comment: Добавил скрины посмотрите пж

Comment: Задавали пароль с помощью smbpasswd?

Comment: Блин, ну нафига текст выкладывать как картинку? Что за вконтактевская привычка? А поисковик как парсить этот мусор будет?